# Question about sensor inputs

Tags: navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Just a general question about Robot_Localization. If a sensor provides velocitys and accelerations (like an IMU) and in the launch file for RL I set the absolute (x,y,z) position field to TRUE will RL integrate my velocity to give that position information or will it just ignore it?

In general how would we go about tuning the process noise matrix? Or would you advise not messing with that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229292/question-about-sensor-inputs/) by [Wagner2x](https://answers.ros.org/users/25690/wagner2x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should only set fields to *true* if they are directly measured by your sensor. The filter will handle integration of acceleration and velocity.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2016-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0